# cant get content by ContentChildren

Tags: angular

I'm in situation where I have a 'Items' component that has ng-content:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'items'
 template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
```

I would like to get the value of this content, so that's why I'm using ContentChildren where I passed my 'Item' directive as selector.

```
@ContentChildren(Item) elements: QueryList<Item>;
```

Unfortunately I can't get any data.

Here I attach a link to [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GANTJuxvhEl8XbMahQXQ)

In elements property I would like to have all elements from 'App' component that I've marked with 'Item' directive.

```
<items>
  <div item *ngFor="let num of nums">{{ num }}</div>
</items>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong selector for Item component. It should be

`[item]` because you use it as attribute

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VlMCcGy9Jl00HgFeuVoo?p=preview)**